# JNI: Bitmap from unsigned char* always null

Tags: java, android, c++, bitmap, java-native-interface

I would like to pass an image (via jni) from C++ to an android application. I am starting from an `unsigned char*` array. This array is not corrupted whatsoever; I am even able to save it into a `ppm` file and display it properly on my laptop.

Then, I convert it to a `jByteArray` by using this function:

```
jbyteArray imgByte=as_byte_array(env,imgRaw,img.getRawImageSize());
...
jbyteArray as_byte_array(JNIEnv *env, unsigned char* buf, int len) {
    jbyteArray array = env->NewByteArray (len);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion (array, 0, len, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(buf));
    return array;
}
```

Afterward, I send this `jByteArray` to the java side. This variable has been properly populated, as I can see by printing its hex values on LogCat:

```
07-01 18:02:45.941    7017-8238/com.myapp.myapp W/C++ side﹕  798a95798b9677889371838d6b7d8664757e5d6e7860717b5e...
07-01 18:02:46.941    7017-8238/com.myapp.myapp W/Java side﹕ 798a95798b9677889371838d6b7d8664757e5d6e7860717b5e...
```

The final step would be to show it on an ImageView. To this end, I do the following code (taken from another question on SO):

```
public void setImageViewWithByteArray(final ImageView view, byte[] data) {
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (bitmap==null) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Bitmap is NULL!");
                view.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_btn_radio_material);
            }
            else {
                view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

but the `bitmap` variable is always `null`. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to debug `decodeByteArray`?

Comment: May be you are getting empty data. Once check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BitmapFactor.decodeByteArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)) is for decoding *compressed* image data, for example the contents of a PNG file.

If your byte array contains uncompressed RGB data, then you can [create a mutable Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)) of the correct width and height and then set the pixels using [Bitmap.setPixels](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). However, setPixels takes an array of ints with 32-bit ARGB values, and from your log it looks like your byte array contains 3-bytes-per-pixel RGB data.

So you'll need to create an int array, then process your byte array and write one int value to the int array for every byte triple, e.g:

```
intArray[i] = 0xff000000 |
    (((int)data[i*3] & 255) << 16) | (((int)data[i*3+1] & 255) << 8) | ((int)data[i*3+2] & 255);
```

Then pass it to setPixels. Or you could do it on the JNI side and return a jintArray.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this solves 80% of my problems. You are right, I have an array of uncompressed RGB data. I followed your suggestions (code here http://pastebin.com/SespEigv ) but now I have two problems: 1 each time I run this code it takes me ~1s for a 320x240 image. Is there a way to fasten up this process? I would like to be as close to, let's say, 30fps, as possible 2 the image is there, but its colors are messed up. I am pretty sure that the jni byte array is coded in RGB; so, why my colors are so strange?

Comment: If the colors are messed up it could be due to the RGB order. I don't know what order your data is in but try intArray[i] = 0xff000000 |
    ((int)data[i*3+2] << 16) | ((int)data[i*3+1] << 8) | (int)data[i*3]; As for the speed issue, I don't think that the color conversion would take 1 second for a 320x240 image, are you doing some other processing on the JNI side beforehand that could account for that?

Comment: It could be that allocating the byte array each time is slowing it down. You can try allocating it on the Java side once and passing it to the JNI which fills it up, reusing it each time. Likewise don't create the bitmap each time, create it once and reuse.

Comment: One more thing, try masking the bytes with & 255 (see revised answer). Java bytes are signed

Comment: Your last modification (i.e. masking the bytes) was the proper way to go. I even managed to optimize my code a bit, and it is much faster (even though I would like to improve it - still have to try with the allocation of the bitmap once in the Java side). Thanks for your help!